# Alexandrov compactification of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm trying to demonstrate that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ using this hint: if $\widehat{X}$ is the Alexandrov compactification of $X$, and $\mathbb{R}^2 \cong \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$, then $\widehat{\mathbb{R}^2} \cong \widehat{\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}}$. This is not true, because $\widehat{\mathbb{R}^2} \cong S^2$, **while if we take any neighbourhood of $\infty$ sufficiently small in $\widehat{\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}}$, this is disconnected by $\infty$. This is false for every point of $S^2$, so $\widehat{\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}} \not\cong S^2$.**

I'm trying to demonstrate the bold part using the properties of Alexandrov compactification, but I'm going nowhere.

Just to be clear, $S^2=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid \left\| x \right\|_E=1\}$ where $\left\| \cdot \right\|_E$ is the euclidean norm, and the Alexandrov compactification is defined the following way: given $(X,\tau)$ topological space, $\infty \notin X$, let $\widehat{X}=X \cup \{\infty\}$ and $\widehat{\tau}=\tau \cup \{A \cup \{\infty\} \mid X \setminus A \text{ is closed and compact in } X\}$

Comment: Easy exercise: the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$ is $S^2/\sim$ where $\sim$ identifies a pair of antipodal points.

Comment: While this is not what you ask for, there are much easier ways of showing that $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$ not are not homeomorphic

Comment: Any neighborhood of $\infty$ in $\widehat{\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}}$ will contain points from $\mathbb R^2$ near $0$ and points far from $0$. If the neighborhood of $\infty$ is sufficiently small, it won't contain any connection between those two parts.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus\{0\}$ is contained in the compact annulus $\{x| 1/r \le |x| \le r\}$ for some $r > 1$. The complement of this annulus in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ is disconnected. Reinterpret this in terms of neighborhoods of $\infty$ in $\widehat{\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus\{0\}}$.